# Cannot install blockchain-wallet-service

Tags: node.js

- My **npm** version is `2.15.1`
- **Node** version is `4.4.3`
- **CentOS** release 6.7 (Final)

When I run

```
npm install -g blockchain-wallet-service
```

Console show error:

> gyp ERR! build error  gyp ERR! stack Error: `make` failed with exit
>   code: 2 gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit
>   (/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/build.js:276:23)
>   gyp ERR! stack     at emitTwo (events.js:87:13) gyp ERR! stack     at
>   ChildProcess.emit (events.js:172:7) gyp ERR! stack     at
>   Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:200:12)
>   gyp ERR! System Linux 2.6.32-573.el6.x86_64 gyp ERR! command
>   "/usr/bin/node"
>   "/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js"
>   "rebuild" gyp ERR! cwd
>   /usr/lib/node_modules/blockchain-wallet-service/node_modules/blockchain.info/node_modules/ws/node_modules/utf-8-validate
>   gyp ERR! node -v v4.4.3 gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.3.1 gyp ERR! not ok

Then I try to run service `blockchain-wallet-service start --port 3000` and try to connect to the service

```
curl -X POST
'http://localhost:3000/api/v2/create?api_code=myCode&password=aPassword'
```

In the service console has message

> Error: RNG.run [ReferenceError: XMLHttpRequest is not defined]
>   1462457502389 - error: Error generating the entropyReferenceError:
>   XMLHttpRequest is not defined

Please tell me how to fix this Issue. The blockchain-wallet-service require `node >= 0.12.0`  and `npm >= 2.12.0, < 3.0.0` .

Here is url that I use [service-my-wallet-v3](https://github.com/blockchain/service-my-wallet-v3).

Comment: I have updated java version 1.8 and I know that the service need java to install. I don't care java 1.8 is problem or not.

Comment: I have answer "jtormey commented 40 minutes ago
Fixed in v0.21.2"